# Can we access NSLog of ViewController1 to another ViewController2, If the NSLog is written in Instance Method of ViewController1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Can we access NSLog and a particular line of code of ViewController1 to another ViewController2, If the NSLog is written in Instance Method of ViewController1

Comment: What do you mean by "access" The log will only print is that instance method is run by the program.

Comment: @Tander I mean that we get the printed data of NSLog into another ViewController class to print that again.

Comment: Please provide your requirement clear - because there is no meaning to pass NSLog data to other viewcontroller as its static string data.

Comment: What do you want exactly please explain briefly its so confusing cant understand.

Comment: Guys just curious about is it possible to access it, or specific line of code.

Comment: @adijazz91 i think you need the value in ViewController2 which is print by NSLog in ViewController1. am i right?

Comment: Guys see this is not my requirement for task. I Just need to know that if the String value which we enter inside NSLog lets say NSLog(@"Hello World!!")    and now this @"Hello world!!" along with the line of code its written on. I want both to access to another viewcontroller class. Is it possible??  P.S: I am asking just for a curiosity guys, don't down vote.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments. This will only happen if you run that method, where the `NSLog` is. You could do it from `ViewController 2` - one way would be like so:

Make the method *public* by placing it in the `.h` file of `ViewController 1` and then passing a reference for `viewController 1` to `viewController 2` - then calling the method directly: `[viewController_1 someMethod];`

One has to ask though - this is rather pointless. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Declare the method, property you want to access in ViewController1.h file. And create an instance in ViewController2 like:

```
ViewController1* vw1 = [[ViewController1 alloc] init];
```

Now access it in:

```
NSLog(@"%i",vw1.myvariable);
[vw1 your_Method];
```

Whatever, study on viewcontroller life cycle, how to pass data from one view to another etc.